# Проверка языка системы

Tags: android

У меня есть страница ошибки подключения.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(){
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/errnoconnect.html");


        }

    });
```

Но как сделать так чтобы на системах с английским языком грузился другой файл?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например, вот так:

```
String language = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
switch (language) {
            case "English":
                // actions
                break;
            case "Russian":
                // actions
                break;
            default:
                // default actions
                break;
        }
```